# Joomla - Image url doubled

Tags: php

Trying to display the avatar(image) from a folder already stored using a form.

Error:
image not displayed.
I found the URL doubled in the inspect element:

---

----------inspect element--------------------------

background-image: url(http://phpstack-130512-487107.cloudwaysapps.com/site/http%3A//phpstack-130502-487107.cloudwaysapps.com/site/components/com_jux_testimonial/uploads/5ad865a54354a-seyaligal-LOGO.jpg);

----------inspect element--------------------------

---

Edited the inspect element code and checked.

----------inspect element edited--------------------------

background-image: url(http://phpstack-130502-487107.cloudwaysapps.com/site/components/com_jux_testimonial/uploads/5ad865a54354a-seyaligal-LOGO.jpg);

----------inspect element edited--------------------------

---

It is now displaying the image.

Screen shot attached.

---

Please advice as to how to debug this issue.

Thanks in advance.

With warm regards,
Venkat Chinniah

[three screen shots merged and attached as one picture][1]

Code part 1:

```
<div class="avatar-testimonial">
<?php
if ($userNameEffects == 1) {
    if ($useGravatar && $item->jux_gravatar) {
        echo '<div class="user_avatar_rotate avatar' . $column . '" style="background-image: url(' . $item->jux_gravatar . '); "></div>';
    } else if ($item->jux_avatar) {
        $jux_avatar = $item->jux_avatar;
        echo '<div class="user_avatar_rotate avatar' . $column . '" style="background-image: url(' . $linkAvatar = JUri::base() . implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $jux_avatar))) . '); "></div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="user_avatar_rotate avatar' . $column . '" style="background-image: url(' . $linkAvatar = JUri::base() . implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $juxAvatarDefault))) . '); "></div>';
    }
    ?>
    <?php
} else {
    if ($useGravatar && $item->jux_gravatar) {
        echo '<div class="user_avatar" style="background-image: url(' . $item->jux_gravatar . '); "></div>';
    } else if ($item->jux_avatar) {
        $jux_avatar = $item->jux_avatar;
        echo '<div class="user_avatar" style="background-image: url(' . $linkAvatar = JUri::base() . implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $jux_avatar))) . '); "></div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="user_avatar" style="background-image: url(' . $linkAvatar = JUri::base() . implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $juxAvatarDefault))) . '); "></div>';
    }
    ?>
<?php }
?>
```

Code Part 2:

```
<div class="avatar-testimonial avatartes<?php echo $column; ?>">
<?php
if ($userNameEffects == 1) {
    if ($useGravatar && $item->jux_gravatar) {
        echo '<div class="user_avatar_rotate avatar' . $column . '" style="background-image: url(' . $item->jux_gravatar . '); "></div>';
    } else if ($item->jux_avatar) {
        $jux_avatar = $item->jux_avatar;
        echo '<div class="user_avatar_rotate avatar' . $column . '" style="background-image: url(' . $linkAvatar = JUri::base() . implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $jux_avatar))) . '); "></div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="user_avatar_rotate avatar' . $column . '" style="background-image: url(' . $linkAvatar = JUri::base() . implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $juxAvatarDefault))) . '); "></div>';
    }
    ?>
    <?php
} else {
    if ($useGravatar && $item->jux_gravatar) {
        echo '<div class="user_avatar" style="background-image: url(' . $item->jux_gravatar . '); "></div>';
    } else if ($item->jux_avatar) {
        $jux_avatar = $item->jux_avatar;
         echo '<div class="user_avatar" style="background-image: url(' . $linkAvatar = JUri::base() . implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $jux_avatar))) . '); "></div>';
     } else {
        echo '<div class="user_avatar" style="background-image: url(' . $linkAvatar = JUri::base() . implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $juxAvatarDefault))) . '); "></div>';
    }
    ?>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: Please improve your code tabbing so that we can read it without doing so much annoying horizontal scrolling.  Do you know about: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/